# Raspberry Pi Z W running on battery and concerns over sudden power cut

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, batterylevel

I'm running a Python script on a Raspberry Pi Zero that records audio, does some processing and TF analysis. Right now the Raspberry is always connected to the power supply, but I want to run while on the move by attaching a battery. However, most of the models of battery and power management boards I have found can't report to the Rasp Pi when the battery is low so you can do a "soft" power down.

1. What is the risk of the Raspberry Pi Z shutting down suddenly when the battery runs out of juice?
2. Is there any option that the power management board has a I2C/GPIO comm with the CPU so you can read the battery level?

Answer (score 0):

Four years ago I worked on a project that used a Raspberry (it wasn't the Pi Z, but I think the problem is similar). We also came across into this problem. So, sharing my experiences with you according your topics:

1. our project was using a battery and sometimes it it runs out of juice. At first it seems ok. But later we got a problem on the SD card that we needed to replace it. So, based on my experience, I don't recommend you to do that
2. In the project we also had a Arduino communicating with the raspberry. So we just use a tensorflow divisor to mesuare the voltage on Arduino analog in, and send it to raspberry using the USB port. Of course, it is not your case, we just use it because we already had this hardware on the project. For your case, I think a safe option is buy a [shield](https://www.pishop.us/amp/product/sleepy-pi-power-management-shield-raspberry-pi/) that do that for you. I don't know your budget, but it's a good idea.